# JDBC Driver Problem in a Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with a Dynamic Web Project, I've been with this error for a couple of weeks and I can not solve it, it's about jdbc driver.

```
public class DatosDAO {

    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BCopia";
    private String usuario = "root";
    private String password = "";

    public DatosDAO() {}


    public boolean alta(Datos d) {

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO datos VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, d.getNombre());
            ps.setString(2, d.getDirectorioOrigen());
            ps.setString(3, d.getDirectorioDestino());
            ps.setInt(4, d.getIntervaloDias());
            ps.executeUpdate();

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();return false;}
        return true;
    }}
```

When attempt to run this method or any other method. I get the following error.

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BCopia at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at
>   modelo.DatosDAO.baja(DatosDAO.java:44) at
>   control.Securalia.baja(Securalia.java:43) etc

I have the driver in lib and have the driver called in the build path and everything else, it is a dynamic web project. Can someone tell me what happens? The DB exists, etc.

Comment: What is the driver file you are using(jar name) and if you are using any kind of IDE is the jar file it in build path?

Comment: it seems that you don't have set your JDBC driver in the classpath.

Comment: I'm using this driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.35 and yes, it's in the build path

Comment: You really should be using a data source in a web application, not `DriverManager`. In any case: make sure the driver is deployed in your application server or in `WEB-INF/lib` (and in that case, you'll need to explicitly load the driver).

Comment: The driver is in lib and with the build path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to add the database driver to the project library. after that you should mention the driver class name here's an example with firebird driver :

```
         Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
```

Check your mysql jdbc driver to find the class name

next you can establish a connection to you're database exactly like you've done with a connection URL and call the driver manager, here's an example :

```
         String connectionURL = "jdbc:firebirdsql://127.0.0.1:3030/c:\\db.fdb";
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, userName,password);
```

good luck !

Comment: Thank you, you saved me :), you are my little hero.

Comment: you're welcome, can you please click the up arrow of the useful answer! thanks

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic Web Project place the driver **JAR file** in the application server's **classpath** and the **WEB-INF/lib** directory of your web application.